# Is there a software that solves this equation.

Tags: math-software, line-integrals

I have a series of equations of the form:
  $p \int_0^\infty   f(x) dx = \int_\delta^\infty   g(x) dx$
where p is a probability (between 0 and 1).

In other words, I have some fraction of the area under the curve, being equal to the area under the curve of another function, starting at point delta, rather then 0. Please note that the two functions are not the same.

I'd like to set the values of p and delta such that the equations balance. This can be fixing, say p, to a constant and solving for \delta or vice versa ( I have small set of values of special interest for each) but even better would be a function or a plot that shows when the equation balances.

My question is is there a softwareor a webservice where I can input my equation and it would return this function\plot\values?

Thanks

Comment: Depending on how the integrands behave you may need a quadrature.

Comment: what is a quadrature?

Comment: It's any type of numerical integration rule.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are common probability density functions this would be easy enough in R.  For example if $f$ was the density of a normal distribution with mean $4$ and standard deviation $3$, and $g$ the density of an exponential distribution with rate $2$ and $p=0.7$ then $\delta$ could be found with something like the following code:  `qexp(1 - 0.7 * (1 - pnorm(0, mean=4, sd=3)), rate=2)` while if $\delta=0.226$ then $p$ could be found with `(1 - pexp(0.226, rate=2)) / (1 - pnorm(0, mean=4, sd=3))`

Comment: Two unknowns makes this tricky. Hard to say exactly what $\{(p,\delta)\}$ looks like without knowing your functions $f$ and $g$. Wolfram alpha can integrate $f$ from zero to infinity however... depending on how nice a function $f$ is..

Comment: f and g are rather simple. but they are not probability density functions.

Comment: p is just a prob. between 2.4% - 21.9%
I have 3  functions I obtained from regression. An example of such a function is
$h_1 =  0.2327 – 0.032954 * ln(x)$
It’s a decreasing fct. I normalized it so it’s between 0-100 by dividing it by its initial (highest ) value

$h’_1 =  0.2327 – 0.032954 * ln(x) / h_1(0)$.
Then I have the two mutually recursive fcts that follow:

$f’= 0.01(h’_1(x)-f(x)  )$ and 

$f(x)=\int_0^\infty f’(x)$

for g is similar except the values of x smaller than $\delta$ = 0,
so the function is

$g(x) =\int_0^\infty f’(x) if x>\delta$
$g(x)=0 if x<=\delta$